# Will there be any trace if I encode video with my laptop?

Tags: image-processing, video, ffmpeg

As the title says 
I want to know if there are anything that will help someone to trace the laptop or machine used for encoding the video?

Also is there any trace in image file too? Like I watermark with ffmpeg and my machine code is added into metadata of that image?

Answer (score 0):

With ffmpeg, no. Add `-bitexact` to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the applicatzion you are using, container and codec you are encoding to, this is possible.

For ffmpeg i am not aware that it puts any machine related stuff into any format or codec.

Even when you are using external encoders instead of built-in ones like AMD or NVIDIA stuff, currently the codecs do not allow to put such data into the stream.

Sure, future audio/video codecs might allow such metadata in order to find out if the encoder is licensed correctly, but as by now i am not aware of such stuff.

What cameras do for example to overcome the lack of codecs and formats support for storage of this information is to just write some xml along to the media file where they store serial number and such.

If there was such information contained, analyzer tools like "mediainfo" would show this info. I am not yet affiliated with mediainfo Sarl.